# XAML = Objects in grid are not visible

Tags: xaml

I'm learning XAML right now and i want to create simple music player but i have a little problem. If i define second, third... grid, objects in this grid are not visible (only in first grid are visible). Can u help me?

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="53"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="75"></RowDefinition>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Rectangle Fill="#333333"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Height="128"
                 Grid.RowSpan="2"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="480"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
      <Button CommandParameter="alarm"
              Click="PlaySound"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Content="►"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="75"
              Height="75"
              Style="{StaticResource Rounded}"
              FontFamily="Arial"
              FontSize="20" />
      <Button VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Content=" ▌▌"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="75"
              Height="75"
              Style="{StaticResource Rounded}"
              FontFamily="Arial"
              FontSize="15" />
      <Button VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Content="■"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="75"
              Height="75"
              Style="{StaticResource Rounded}"
              FontFamily="Arial"
              FontSize="25" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Text="song_name"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                 Height="53"
                 Width="auto"
                 FontSize="30"
                 Margin="12,0,0,0" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="53"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="75"></RowDefinition>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Rectangle Fill="#333333"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Height="128"
                 Grid.RowSpan="2"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="480"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
      <Button CommandParameter="alarm"
              Click="PlaySound"
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Content="►"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="75"
              Height="75"
              Style="{StaticResource Rounded}"
              FontFamily="Arial"
              FontSize="20" />
      <Button VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Content=" ▌▌"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="75"
              Height="75"
              Style="{StaticResource Rounded}"
              FontFamily="Arial"
              FontSize="15" />
      <Button VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Content="■"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="75"
              Height="75"
              Style="{StaticResource Rounded}"
              FontFamily="Arial"
              FontSize="25" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 Text="song_name"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                 Height="53"
                 Width="auto"
                 FontSize="30"
                 Margin="12,0,0,0" />
    </Grid>
  </StackPanel>
```

Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2fLm.png

Comment: What type of XAML project; WPF, Windows Phone, Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

You are not being explicit with your grid location assignments.

Where is the Grid.Row and Grid.Column here?

```
<Rectangle Fill="#333333" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>
```

Comment: Grid.RowSpan = "2"
Grid.ColumnSpan = "4"

i added Grid.Row and Column... but still same problem. Objects in second grid dont show

Comment: Did you update second grid as well with the changes?